# JavaScript split at a maths operator while still including it

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Okay...
I'm trying to split a string of text up into an array where instances of '+' or '-' appear. First of all I need to know how to split at the plus sign and include it.

I have tried this: `'3+5'.split(/(?='+')/)` and the result I want is `["3","+5"]` but it doesn't seem to work and only produces and array of `["3+5"]` which is cool but not what I'm looking for. All the resources I have found say that this should work but it doesn't how I want it. I tried it with commas in place of the plus sign and it yields the result I was looking for but I kind of need it for the plus sign.

Secondly I would like to split it at a minus in the same way as well. The plus not working I don't really have code for it but I assume it goes a little like this from the resources I found: `'3+5-2'.split(/(?=+) | (?=-)/)` with the result of `["3","+5","-2"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want `/(?=[+])/` or `/(?=\+)/` rather than `/(?='+')/`.

The `+` needed to be escaped.

```
'3+5'.split(/(?=[+])/);
// ["3", "+5"]
```

or:

```
'3+5'.split(/(?=\+)/);
// ["3", "+5"]
```

If you want to include `-` as a delimiter:

```
'3+5-2'.split(/(?=[+-])/);
// ["3", "+5", "-2"]
```